# How to get Current Module and Full Action Name in ajax controller

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax

I need Full Action Name in Ajax Controller Magento 2.

```
protected $request;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {

    $this->request = $request;
}

$action = $this->request->getFullActionName();
```

This always giving me my ajax controller full action name.

I need, suppose if I m on the product page this should give me "catalog_product_view".

If I m on search this should display "catalogsearch_result_index".

Please help.

Comment: Try `$this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()` or   use `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` instead of `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to check controller, module and action

```
echo $controllerName = $this->request->getControllerName();
echo $actionName = $this->request->getActionName();
echo $routeName = $this->request->getRouteName();
echo $moduleName = $this->request->getModuleName();
```

By concatenation, you can get your required result

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get your result

```
protected $request;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {

    $this->request = $request;
}

$action = $this->request->getModuleName()."_".$this->request->getControllerName()."_".$this->request->getActionName()
```

Comment: This I tried it will not work...I m asking about ajax controller.